# Convert list of 100 images into array in R

Tags: r, keras

I have a leaf color image which I have resized to 28 by 28 and converted to grayscale

```
str(mypic)
>  List of 100
> $ : num [1:28, 1:28] 0.246 0.413 0.62 0.629 0.773 ...
> $ :Formal class 'Image' [package "EBImage"] with 2 slots
>  .. ..@ .Data    : num [1:28, 1:28] 0.6614 0.0556 0.5165 0.4018 0.4214 ...
>  .. ..@ colormode: int 0
```

How do I convert these into an array of 100 by 28 by 28

Comment: This worked for me : #convert to array from list of both  images and labels to match like MNIST
myp<- array(as.numeric(unlist(mypic)), dim=c(100,28,28))
str(myp)
try <- array(as.numeric(unlist(trainy)), dim=c(100,1))
str(try)

Answer (score 0):

a1 is 2x2x3 and a2 is 3x2x2:

```
m <- matrix(1:4, 2)
L <- list(m, 10*m, 100*m)
a1 <- array(unlist(L), c(2, 2, 3))
a2 <- aperm(a1, c(3, 1, 2))
```